# If $|x_{n+1}-x_n| < |x_n-x_{n-1}|$, then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove or disprove :

If $|x_{n+1}-x_n| < |x_n-x_{n-1}|$ for all $n\geq 2$, then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence

What I understand from this is if the difference between the $n$ and $n+1$ terms in the sequence is getting smaller and smaller, then, the sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

I am pretty sure it it is not. I thought of the logarithmic structure, but I don't think I can use that yet (we haven't seen it yet). I then thought of the square root function whose terms are in fact getting smaller and smaller relative to the preceding one.

However, I fail to see how to prove that formally... What arguments can I invoke? Can I manipulate the expression and how?

Comment: That is correct! I will edit. Thanks

Comment: Use the definition involving $\epsilon$

Comment: What is the definition of Cauchy sequence are you using?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl21lutUIXk this would be **very** helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n=\sqrt{n}$. Note that for $n\ge 2$, we have  $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\lt \sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}$.  This can be seen, for example, by rationalizing the numerators, and rewriting the inequality as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}$.

The sequence $(x_n)$ is not Cauchy, since however big $m$ is, by choosing a suitable $n\gt m$ we can make $\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}$ arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Take a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, $a_n\searrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$. (There are classical examples of this!)

Consider 
$$
x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k.
$$
It is certainly true that $\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n\rvert<\lvert x_n-x_{n-1}\rvert$; can you prove that $(x_n)$ is not Cauchy?